# Angular Charts not display

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, charts, angular-chart

Trying to work with angular charts with chart.js bundle taken from the cdn links. Angular is 1.5.7 and chart.js is 2.1.6.
I get the following error:

> angular.js:13708 TypeError: (intermediate value)[type] is not a function
>       at createChart (angular-chart.js:197)
>       at angular-chart.js:150
>       at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17286)
>       at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17552)
>       at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1754)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4709)
>       at doBootstrap (angular.js:1752)
>       at bootstrap (angular.js:1772)
>       at angularInit (angular.js:1657)
>       at angular.js:31468

HTML Code:

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/Chart.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/angular/angular-chart.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/angular/angular-chart.css"/>

        <title>Practice</title>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="appName" ng-controller="indexController">

        <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series"></canvas>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript file:

```
var appOne = angular.module('appName', ['chart.js']);


appOne.controller("indexController", function ($scope) {
   $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];

  $scope.data = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  ];
});
```

Any ideas what is wrong and how to fix it? I don't understand the error too. Cheers :)

Comment: What are your  angular and chart.js versions ?

Comment: @UgoT. Angular is 1.5.7 and chart.js is 2.1.6... I need to keep the angular version the same. ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was due to the versions of angular-chart.js and chart.js were not compatible with each other.

I ended up using the latest angular-chart.js 1.0.0-alpha version with chart.js 2.0.

That fixed the issue! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `chart-series` attribute.

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar"
  chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series"> 
</canvas
```

Comment: Shouldn't chart-series be inside the tags?

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue though

Comment: Take a look at it https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/372